# Using a FK for the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I created a table inside my database named categories:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` 
( `categoryName` varchar(128)  ,
 `subcategoryName` varchar(128) ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`categoryName`) )
 ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

A category in this table may be a subcategory of another category in this field.So,subcategory is a FK to categories.Initialiasiation:

```
ALTER TABLE `category` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`subcategoryName`) REFERENCES `category`(`categoryName`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

So i tried inserting values in this table like this:

```
INSERT INTO `category` (`categoryName`, `subcategoryName`) VALUES
( 'Literature','Satire'),
( 'Science','Mathematics'),
( 'Science','Physics');
```

This however gives me this error:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`php_beginner_crud_level_1`.`category`, CONSTRAINT `category_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`subcategoryName`) REFERENCES `category` (`categoryName`))
```

Any ideas about why is this happening and how do i solve this?

Comment: The error seems obvious.  You cannot insert rows into subcategories, until the categories for them already exist.

Comment: @GordonLinoff After inserting signle values to the categoryName column how can i add subcategories binded to these categories added?

Comment: Try to think this table like this, more easy: `CREATE TABLE  category ( category varchar(128) not null , categoryParent varchar(128) null references category, ... `